# Wine error in 10.10

Tags: 10.10, wine

I tried to run a windows software on wine and i get this error
[image]
It is an online test software, i.e it enables me to take a test online. thats the most description i can give.
Any help? Please i need this to work urgently

Comment: add more information: what kind of software it is?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319844 . Try the things they have suggested and add more details to the question.

Comment: I previously have downloaded a online test software of AIEEE. I used virtual box with windows xp on it to ran that software. If wine doesn't works for you then have a look at virtual box....

Comment: @Ravi i know i can do that but i dont have much space on my hard disk to run Xp under virtual box.

Comment: @harisibrahimkv i dont know how to use those solutions on wine. i think they are meant just for windows.

Comment: @Ashu Oh, sorry. Looking at the screenshot I think that there is some ActiveX error stuff. Does the software you downloaded use IE (Internet Explorer.) What is the name of the software?

Comment: @Ravi It is the software from the [bitsat website](http://www.bitsadmission.com/bitsat/bitsatmain.htm) ... i dont think it uses IE

Comment: @Ashu, you'd be very surprised by the number of applications that embed IE into them to do various different things. The SDK from Microsoft allows you to embed IE into your application to either allow formatting of text, to grab images from the web, connecting to a server, etc. Since it is an online test, it is very likely that this is what its doing, it basically embeds their webpage into an application for simplicity. Have a look at my answer below, I've mentioned how to install Direct X and also IE6... those should fix your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing Direct X using a tool called `winetricks`, since it seems the error is related to that.

1. Get winetricks: Open up a terminal, and type in `sudo apt-get install winetricks`.
2. Run winetricks and install Direct X: You have 2 ways of doing this.

   1. Run winetricks itself and install the components you need (e.g. Direct X 9, or d3dx9 as its called, will be a good start!)
   2. Alternatively use the terminal directly to install them, e.g. `winetricks d3dx9`.

Please note you may also need IE6 (or above) since it sounds like its using an ActiveX COM (which only IE uses, afaik). Using winetricks you can get this too!

- Either use the tool, or type in: `winetricks ie6` in a terminal.

Hope this helps, let me know if this works.

Please check [WineHQ App Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/) (search is on the top-right) to see if your application you're trying to use is listed, since it might give you better steps to get it to work.

**References:**

- [WineHQ Forums View topic - how to use directx10 11](http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?p=62550&sid=b9bfe5e8182d5641f3505a1370e227d8)
- [Native D3DX9 - The Official Wine Wiki](http://wiki.winehq.org/Native_D3DX9)
- [WineHQ - Wine Application Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/)